# Trying to figure out how to error handler into this candy machine program

Tags: java, user-interface, error-handling

Got this program for a candy machine GUI finished, but I can't figure out where to put in the InputMismatchException code. I've tried putting it in under the input for entering the payments, but I can't find a way to put it in the right area, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Main Candy Machine Class**

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class candyMachine extends JFrame {
    //window size setup
    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    //setup for the store items and register
    private CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister();
    private Dispenser candy = new Dispenser(100, 50);
    private Dispenser chips = new Dispenser(100, 65);
    private Dispenser gum = new Dispenser(75, 45);
    private Dispenser cookies = new Dispenser(100, 85);
    //heading and button setups
    private JLabel headingMainL;
    private JLabel selectionL;

    private JButton exitB, candyB, chipsB, gumB, cookiesB;
    private ButtonHandler pbHandler;
    //the main machine constructor
    public candyMachine() {

        setTitle("Candy Machine"); // window title
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);    // window size

        Container pane  = getContentPane();  //container get
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1)); //pane layout setup

        pbHandler = new ButtonHandler();  //instantiate listener object

        //Store sign setup
        headingMainL = new JLabel("WELCOME TO SHELLY'S CANDY SHOP", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //instructions setup
        selectionL = new JLabel("To Make a Selection, " + "Click on the Product Button", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //adding the labels to the panes
        pane.add(headingMainL); 
        pane.add(selectionL); 

        //candy button setup
        candyB = new JButton("Candy"); 
        //registering the listener for the candy button
        candyB.addActionListener(pbHandler);

        //chip button setup
        chipsB = new JButton("Chips");
        //Registering listener for chips button
        chipsB.addActionListener(pbHandler); 

        //gum button setup
        gumB = new JButton("Gum");
        //registering the listener for the gum button
        gumB.addActionListener(pbHandler); 

        //cookie button setup
        cookiesB = new JButton("Cookies");
        //registering the listener for the cookie button
        cookiesB.addActionListener(pbHandler);

        //exit button setup
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");
        //registering the listener for the exit button
        exitB.addActionListener(pbHandler);

        pane.add(candyB); //adds the candy button to the pane
        pane.add(chipsB); //adds the chips button to the pane
        pane.add(gumB); //adds the gum button to the pane
        pane.add(cookiesB); //adds the cookies button to the pane
        pane.add(exitB); //adds the exit button to the pane

        setVisible(true); //show the window and its contents
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    //class to handle button events
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
                System.exit(0);
            else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Candy"))
                sellProduct(candy, "Candy");
            else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Chips"))
                sellProduct(chips, "Chips");
            else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Gum"))
                sellProduct(gum, "Gum");
            else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Cookies"))
                sellProduct(cookies, "Cookies");
        }
    }

    //Method to sell machine items
    private void sellProduct(Dispenser product, String productName) {
        //int variables for the amount of money entered, prices, and money needed
        int coinsInserted = 0;
        int price;
        int coinsRequired;

        String str;
        // if statement for buying the products
        
        
        if (product.getCount() > 0) {

            price = product.getProductCost();
            coinsRequired = price - coinsInserted;

            
            while (coinsRequired > 0) {
                
                    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("To buy " + productName + " please insert " + coinsRequired + " cents");
                    coinsInserted = coinsInserted
                            + Integer.parseInt(str);
                    coinsRequired = price - coinsInserted;
            }

            cashRegister.acceptAmount(coinsInserted);
            product.makeSale();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please pick up " + "your " + productName + " and enjoy",
                    "Thank you, Come again!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else //if that item is sold out
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry " + productName + " is sold out\n" + "Please make another selection",
                        "Thank you, Come again!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        
    }
    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        candyMachine candyShop = new candyMachine();

    }
}
```

**Cash Register Class**

```
public class CashRegister {


    private int regiCash; //int variable for storing cash in the "register"


    public CashRegister()
    { // default amount of cash on hand is 500
        regiCash = 500;
    }

    //Method that receives the cash entered by the user and updates the register
    public void acceptAmount(int amountIn) {

        regiCash = regiCash + amountIn;

    }

    //Constructer for setting the amount of money in the register to a specific amount (500)
    public CashRegister(int cashIn)
    {
        if (cashIn >= 0)
            regiCash = cashIn;
        else
            regiCash = 500;
    }

    //Method to show the current amount of money in the cash register
    public int currentBalance()
    {
        return regiCash;
    }


}
```

**Dispenser Class**

```
public class Dispenser {

    private int itemNumber;   //int variable for storing the number of items in the dispenser
    private int price; //int variable for storing item prices
    
    //item constructor
    public Dispenser(int i, int j)
    { //default number of items is 5 and default price is 50
        itemNumber = 5;
        price = 50;
    }


    public int getCount()
    {
        return itemNumber;
    }


    public void makeSale()
    {
        itemNumber--;
    }


    public int getProductCost()
    {
        return price;
    }
}
```

**Button Handler Class**

```
package lab9Final;

public class ButtonHandler {
    //Handles the buttons
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't depend on exceptions for normal flow control.  I.e. don't rely on `InputMismatchException`, read the input into a string buffer and validate it yourself, taking whatever action is appropriate if the input is invalid.  That way your program's normal flow is not disrupted, and you don't have to write an ugly hack if you really want the program to recover and continue.

Comment: alright, where and how exactly do i do that?
thank you

Comment: Where do you think `InputMismatchException` would be thrown?  Under what conditions? That's where you put the code to validate the input.